# Update data in my application only to active users

Tags: java, android

I have a finance application to save information on monetary loans (already in production), for each loan you can select the periodicity of the payment dates, the periodicity is selected by the user of a spinner and stored in a database, these are the options:

Weekly         (position 0 in spinner)

Monthly        (position 1 in spinner)

Bimonthly      (position 2 in spinner)

Quarterly      (position 3 in spinner)

Biannual       (position 4 in spinner)

Annual         (position 5 in spinner)

Currently stores the position of the spinner (in each loan) in the database to save the periodicity

In my new update I want to add a new periodicity option "Biweekly" and to maintain the order I want to put it after "Weekly", that is to say that the positions will be traversed thus:

Weekly         (position 0 in spinner)

Biweekly       (position 1 in spinner)

Monthly        (position 2 in spinner)

Bimonthly      (position 3 in spinner)

Quarterly      (position 4 in spinner)

Biannual       (position 5 in spinner)

Annual         (position 6 in spinner)

For new users there is no problem, but for active users I have to change the values that have been traversed, I know how to do it but I don't know when to do it, I have the updatePositions () function but, how do I tell Android to which users it should be applied and How do I tell you that it should only be applied once?

Comment: Use the version tag of your app.

Comment: Excuse me but I do not understand, all users who download the new version (1.0.2) will have that same version also if I upload another update 1.0.3 and someone updates from 1.0.1 they will not have gone through 1.0.2